# Filtering contacts to display or show only set number of contacts

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

My app is calling pickMultipleContactAsync  method that returns a list of contacts. If I want to filter only particular contats to display or show only a set number of contacts, does WinJS provide any specific methods or patterns to do this? I know since its a list, I probably can use some standard predicate type of thing to do this type of filtering, but I wonder if there is anything specific WinJS API to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`WinJS.Binding.List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx) uses a feature called "projection" to create a second list filtered by a predicate which will automatically update itself as the origin list changes.
Use the `createFiltered` function, then you can use the resulting list for example in a `WinJS.UI.ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679973%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) can be used in this case.

```
var picker = Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
picker.commitButtonText = "Select";
picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function (contacts)
{
    var contactsStartingWithPrefixPa = contacts.filter(function filterContacts(contact)
    {
        if (contact.name.match(/^Pa/))
            return true;
        return false;
    });
});
```